# Scala Implicit class member is not accessible in object

Tags: scala, bcrypt, scala-implicits

I am using Scala bCrypt [wrapper](https://github.com/t3hnar/scala-bcrypt) for encrypting user password, this wrapper provides an implicit class.

```scala
package object bcrypt {

  implicit class Password(val pswrd: String) extends AnyVal {
    def bcrypt: String = B.hashpw(pswrd, BCrypt.gensalt())

    def bcrypt(rounds: Int): String = B.hashpw(pswrd, BCrypt.gensalt(rounds))

    def bcrypt(salt: String): String = B.hashpw(pswrd, salt)

    def isBcrypted(hash: String): Boolean = B.checkpw(pswrd, hash)
  }

  def generateSalt: String = B.gensalt()
}
```

But I am facing a strange problem, whenever I am using this Implicit converision in **class** it workes fine but converiosn doesnt work with **object** or **case classes**.

```scala
scala> import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt._
import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt._

scala> class Password(secret: String) {
     |   def validate(userSecret: String): Boolean = userSecret.isBcrypted(secret)
     | 
     |   override def toString = secret
     | }
defined class Password

scala> object Password {
     |   def apply(secret: String): Password = new Password(secret)
     | 
     |   def getEncrypted(secret: String) = new Password(secret.bcrypt)
     | }
<console>:18: error: value bcrypt is not a member of String
         def getEncrypted(secret: String) = new Password(secret.bcrypt)
                                                                ^

scala>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any stable identifier shadows imported `implicit` identifiers. Things that can shadow implicits include `val`, `def`, `object` and the generated companion object of `case class`. Simple `class`es and `type`s don't create identifiers and thus don't shadow imported `implicit` identifiers.

`implicit class Password` is just syntactic sugar for a `class Password` and an `implicit def Password`, and so an identifier in your code named `Password` would shadow that `implicit def`.

So while this code compiles OK:

```
object Foo {
  import bcrypt._
  class Password()
  "123".bcrypt
}
```

All of the following snippets will fail to compile:

```
object Foo2 {
  import bcrypt._
  val Password = 1
  "123".bcrypt
}

object Foo3 {
  import bcrypt._
  def Password() = 1
  "123".bcrypt
}

object Foo4 {
  import bcrypt._
  case class Password()
  "123".bcrypt
}

object Foo5 {
  import bcrypt._
  object Password
  "123".bcrypt
}
```

The solution in your case is simple: rename the implicit class to something else, that would be unlikely to clash with other identifiers. For example, `implicit class PasswordExtensions`.

If you can't rename the `implicit class` in the original code, you can *import* it under a different name: `import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt.{Password => PasswordExtensions, _}`

Comment: Ok, so turns out it was collision of "Password" as an Identifier was causing this compilation failure, it works by only changing this statement import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt.{Password => BcryptUtil}